# Realm on Android 10 / Android Q always return null

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a codes implement Realm like this:

```
public class ServiceRealm {
    public static Realm getrealm(Context mcontext){
        Realm.init(mcontext);
        return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }
}

..........

RealmResults<Nasa> ra = new ServiceRealm().getrealm(mContext).where(Nasa.class).findAll();
        for (int i = a; i < u; i++) {
            int n = i + 1;
            list.add(new PlanetItem(ra.get(i).getText().replace("\\\n", ""), n + ". " + ra.get(i).getLatin()));
        }
```

on Android 9 and below, everything is work fine, no issue at all on the Log, but when i running this app to Android 10 (Android Q) and Android 11. It always crash just like this Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at d.a.a.y5.a.I(:46)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.T(:4)
    at c.l.a.k.e0(:110)
    at c.l.a.k.c0(:7)
    at c.l.a.k.d0(:7)
    at c.l.a.a.h(:37)
    at c.l.a.k.R(:51)
    at c.l.a.k.j0(:10)
    at c.l.a.q.b(:9)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.r(:112)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(:25)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27128)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7340)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27128)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7340)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27128)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7340)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(:21)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27128)
```

In gradle.build:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 39
        versionName "21.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError true
    }
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module: 'annotation'
}
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Any help? what the cause and how to fix this for Android 10 and above.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be posting a `de-obfuscated` stacktrace.

Comment: @DarShan doesn't have it, because the crash is from users using TestFairy. Any help?